# MVC4 RC How to use JSON.NET with MVC controller

Tags: json.net

I am using MVC4 RC and I read that MVC4 uses JSON.NET as the default JSON Serializer/DeSerializer.
I am not using Web Api and just using default MVC controllers.
When I break on Application_Start and browse through ValueProvidersFactories, I still find JSONValueProviderFactory, which internally uses JavaScriptSerializer.

> ?ValueProviderFactories.Factories
>   Count = 6
>
> [0]: {System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionValueProviderFactory}
>
> [1]: {System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory}
>
> [2]: {System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory} <--
>
> [3]: {System.Web.Mvc.RouteDataValueProviderFactory}
>
> [4]: {System.Web.Mvc.QueryStringValueProviderFactory}
>
> [5]: {System.Web.Mvc.HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory}

So to use JSON.NET, do I still need to create my own ValueProviderFactory (as done [here](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099)) Or I am missing something in the whole picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So to use JSON.NET, do I still need to create my own
>   ValueProviderFactory (as done here) Or I am missing something in the
>   whole picture?

No, you are not missing anything. You debugged and understood perfectly fine the whole picture. If you want to use JSON.NET with standard ASP.NET MVC controllers (not Web API) you have to roll your own Json value provider factory.

Comment: so WebApi uses JSON.NET by default?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, yes it does.

Comment: I don't understand why they still haven't come up with a replacement JSON.NET value provider for MVC